# Blocking only a certain subpage of a website

Tags: http, http-proxy

Is it possible to blocking only a certain subpage of a website instead of all domain by modifying `/etc/hosts` file? For example I want to block `http://example.com/whatever.html` instead of all domain `http://example.com`. I tried to put just `0.0.0.0 http://example.com/whatever.html` but it does not work.

Comment: No, /etc/hosts provides a local mapping of hostnames ("www.example.com") to IPv4 or IPv6 addresses.  It is not a mechanism for redirecting URLs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

`/etc/hosts` is used to modify the "hostname -> IP address" mapping.  It can ***not*** be used for "protocol layer" filtering.

If you want to limit specific pages then you need to use something like a proxy server.  This can be programmed with specific rules to permit/deny certain pages.  Then configure your browser to use that proxy.

A simple example of this is Privoxy (https://www.privoxy.org/) but there are lots of tools.

EDIT TO ADD:  Alternatively a browser *plugin* (eg "ublock origin" or "adblock plus") can be configured to block access to pages directly inside the browser.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/hosts` only affects your server's access to external *hosts* (not locations on those hosts), and is not useful for controlling access to your webserver (unless the only users you are concerned about are *local* users *on* the same machine).

The usual way for limiting access is by the `.htaccess` file, which you can put in "any" directory to control access to that directory and its subdirectories.  Like proxy servers, there are pros/cons for using it.  Others generally advise using SSL and authentication, but that's a large topic.

Further reading:

- [Apache HTTP Server Tutorial: .htaccess files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html)

  > You should avoid using `.htaccess` files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in a [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory) block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.
- [location of .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756768/location-of-htaccess-file) (neither answer is good)
- [How To Use the .htaccess File](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file)

  > Additionally the placement of the `.htaccess` file is important. The configurations in that file will affect everything in its directory and the directories under it.

Comment: Don't think that's what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a truly configurable method, you can use the hosts file to do the domain level redirect, and then have a filter/proxy server hosted either at localhost or on a networked computer so do the protocol/file level blocking. it is possible to do even with simple htaccess or server config files. the hosts file will be used to redirect traffic to your own server, and then your server will do the blocking or redirecting as necessary.